# GRASS-GIS i.pansharpen error code -11

Tags: raster-conversion, grass-7.0, pansharpening

I have been searching for similar problems however i did not find any that could fix my error. 
i have GRASSGIS 7.0 running on MACOSX El Capitan. No problems at all until i tried to run i.pansharpen on Landsat 8 images.

this is how i set it (no optional values)
[image: i.pansharpen settings]

it tooks a very long time almost freezing on

> i.pansharpen --overwrite red=LC80340432016029LGN00_B3@PERMANENT
>   green=LC80340432016029LGN00_B2@PERMANENT
>   blue=LC80340432016029LGN00_B1@PERMANENT
>   pan=LC80340432016029LGN00_B8@PERMANENT output=2016_pan_ method=brovey
>   Performing pan sharpening with hi res pan image: 15.000000 
>   Histogram matching... 
>   Histogram matching... 
>   Histogram matching... 
>   Calculating Brovey transformation...

then after a while it goes like this:

> Performing pan sharpening with hi res pan image: 15.000000 
>   Histogram matching... 
>   Histogram matching... 
>   Histogram matching...
>   Calculating Brovey transformation... 
>   Assigning grey equalized color tables to
>   output images... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/scripts/i .pansharpen",
>   line 452, in 
>       main()   File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/scripts/i .pansharpen",
>   line 319, in main
>       flags="e", color='grey')   File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/pytho
>   n/grass/script/core.py", line 395, in run_command
>       return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)   File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/pytho
>   n/grass/script/core.py", line 313, in handle_errors
>       returncode=returncode) grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None ['r.colors', '--q', '-e', 'color=grey', 'map=2016_pan__red']
>   ended with error **Process ended with non-zero return code -11. See
>   errors in the (error) output.**

after that the output is created empty...

i do not understand what is the error, and how i could fix it, i have been extensively searching for a similar problem but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/214337/edit) your text to provide an actual question. At the moment it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry you are right, the last part was cutted when i published the question.

Comment: This is only a wild guess, but have you tried with different output file name? I also have a (different) problem with grass on fresh installed system, it isn't that stable

Comment: @adamczi not so wild as guess, i tried because output names gave me problems too in the past, also i tried to run in serial processing rather than parallel, to allow overwriting files, tried all three methods, different landsat bands, different landsat files... nothing... same error...